# How do you get your modifiers to be on your paypal invoice?

Tags: expresso-store

When a purchase is made with exp-resso Store and the payment is sent to paypal the customer and company both receive an email receipt from paypal.

Problem is the paypal receipt does not contain the product modifiers.  HOw do I get these added to the paypal invoice/receipt?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to update the files to get more information passed to PayPal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open up the PayPal payment gateway file and search for the relevant code to send the line item data and then add code to loop through any modifiers for each item in the cart.

Comment: wow that is quite surprising that you have to hack the code in order to do this.  Seems like a bug to me.  If someone orders a Small Red Tshirt, you would think it would be important to have that info on the paypal receipt.

Comment: Also seems impossible to even find the file for the paypal gateway.  At least I can't locate it.

Comment: Store has the ability to send out order receipts would be my thought of why it is not included in the PayPal gateway by default but I don't know for sure.

Comment: You should be able to find it it store/vendor/omnipay folder